# How to use if statement in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, relational-operators

I am habituated to Python where the following code works without any exceptions. However, I am getting the below error in R when I try to run the command.

```
a <- readline(prompt="Give a num between 1-10: ")
b <- readline(prompt="Give another between 11-20: ")

if((1 <= a <= 10) & (11 <= b <= 20)) {
  a <- a
  b <- b
} else {
  a <- readline(prompt="Give a correct num between 1-10: ")
  b <- readline(prompt="Give a correct num between 11-20: ")
}
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: you can't do  a <= b <= c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Although, `1 <= a <= 10` seems logically correct it isn't a valid syntax in R. You need to use `1 >= a & a <= 10` separately.

2) output of `readline` is a character, you might want to wrap `as.numeric` to get a number.

3) No need to assign `a` and `b` again, it is already present if the contion is `TRUE`.

So to summarise you can do :

```
a <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Give a num between 1-10: "))
b <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Give another between 11-20: "))

if(a < 1 | a > 10) 
   a <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Give a correct num between 1-10: "))
if(b < 11 | b > 20))
   b <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Give a correct num between 11-20: "))
```